# 'us-ascii' is not a supported encoding name on Windows Phone 8/Azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to test the Microsoft Azure's Mobile Services. I've created a Mobile Service on the  Azure portal and downloaded the "getting started" project with the Todo demo application.
I was able to deploy the service on the cloud and to run the app with the simulator but when a I try to host the service on my local IIS and run the mobile app, I've got the following exception on the client side:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'us-ascii' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name
   at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String name)
   at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String name)
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(String name)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ReadAsStringAsync>b__0(Task task)
```

My Windows's language is English and my keyboard's language is French. I tried to configure the encoding of the HTTP requests on both client side and service side but nothing worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting the encoding?

Comment: I've tried using the 'Globalization' element inside the System.Web element of the Web.config (service side).
I've also tried to set the MobileService.SerializerSettings.Culture on the client side.

I've also installed the language 'English (United States)' on Windows because before oding this, the culture 'us-ascii' was not present on my system and not listed by the Encoding.GetEncodings() method.

Comment: Windows phone only supports utf 8 as an Encoding

Comment: So, could it be an error in the local IIS's configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side effect of now allowing your WP8.X Emulator (VM) to connect to your local Service that runs under IIS.

When you create a WCF web service in Visual Studio, by default the service is hosted in IIS Express and only accepts connections at localhost

The Windows Phone 8 Emulator, however, configures itself as a separate device on the network. As a result, an app running on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator can’t connect to the development computer as localhost.

Before you can connect successfully from the emulator to the local web service, you have to follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ReconfiguringthesolutionwhenhostingtheservicewithIISExpress)

In short :

1. Go to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\
2. Open applicationhost.config
3. Add a new Binding with the IP of your WPEmulator VM
4. Restart VS as Admin

Comment: I am trying to connect with Azure Service Bus, and I am getting the same error on Windows Phone. No localhost IIS at play here. What could be wrong?